# symmetric difference of Sets in java

Tags: java, generics, set

I am trying to implement symmetric difference of Sets in java
I have commented the Line where I am missing some concept. Kindly Help !

```
public static <T> Set<T> symmetricDifference(Set<? extends T> set1, Set<? extends T> set2) {
        for(<? extends T> a : set1)
        {
            if(set2.contains(a))
                {
                    set1.remove(a);
                    set2.remove(a);
                }
            else
                set2.add(a);  //what is wrong with this line
        }
        return set2;
    }

}
```

The error on the commented Line is

```
'Main.java:11: error: illegal start of type Set<> ans=new Set<>();
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: 'Main.java:11: error: illegal start of type
        Set<> ans=new Set<>();
            ^'@BenjaminUrquhart

Comment: So the error occurs in code that isn't shown?

Comment: Set is an interface and cannot be instantized. Use one of its implementations like HashSet<> for instance.

Comment: `for(<? extends T> a : set1)` is nonsensical syntax. `for (T a : set1)`. But then you've still got the problem that you can't add to `set2` because of the upper-bounded wildcard.

Comment: "'Main.java:11: error: illegal start of type
        Set<> ans=new Set<>();" where does that appear on the code?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. And do not put such infos into comments, update the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetric difference of two sets is the union of their differences. Now, the problem in your case is that you have a method which returns a set and you modify the input sets, distorting them. You need to create a new Set and add the elements you need. In order to do that you will need to iterate your first set and add the items into the new set which are not found in the second set, and then iterate the second set and add the items to the new set which were not found in the first set. The formula is:

**A △ B = (A – B) ∪ (B – A)**

or:

**A △ B = (A ∪ B) - (A ∩ B)**

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using Java 8 streams:

```
public static <T> Set<T> symmetricDifference(Set<? extends T> set1, Set<? extends T> set2) {
    Set<T> set =  set1.stream()
            .filter(e -> !set2.contains(e))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    set2.stream()
            .filter(e -> !set1.contains(e))
            .forEach(set::add);

    return set;
}
```

or a solution for Java 7 and below:

```
public static <T> Set<T> symmetricDifference2(Set<? extends T> set1, Set<? extends T> set2) {
    Set<T> s = new HashSet<>();

    for (T t1 : set1) {
        if(!set2.contains(t1)) 
            s.add(t1);
    }


    for (T t2 : set2) {
        if(!set1.contains(t2)) 
            s.add(t2);
    }

    return s;
}
```

But however this does not makes much sense. If generic type of set1 differs from generic type of set2 there is not much of a chance to exclude any element because both set1 and set2 will contain different implementations of T (except you forced your equals() and hashCode() methods to do so).

Comment: An easier way with streams would be `Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream()).filter(e -> !set1.contains(e) || !set2.contains(e)).collect(toSet())`.